# Spring SAML redirecs to failureRedirectHandler even on successful authentication

Tags: spring, spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

After successful authentication from the IDP I am being redirected to the defaultFailureUrl  property specified in the bean with id="failureRedirectHandler". Even though I dont have any errors in the response.
This is the SAML response    :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <saml2p:Response xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" Destination="https://vogon.srv.media.net:8080/saml2/acs" ID="_82e963af7e01be8c6b22762ef15b0af4" InResponseTo="a40fdeb955aahd123d63ejegi5feh0f" IssueInstant="2016-08-08T12:49:33.806Z" Version="2.0">
       <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2?idpid=C03r9b88d</saml2:Issuer>
       <saml2p:Status>
          <saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
       </saml2p:Status>
       <saml2:Assertion xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_09e40853eaac6e2dcceecd6da54fc927" IssueInstant="2016-08-08T12:49:33.806Z" Version="2.0">
          <saml2:Issuer>https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2?idpid=C03r9b88d</saml2:Issuer>
          <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
             <ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
                <ds:Reference URI="#_09e40853eaac6e2dcceecd6da54fc927">
                   <ds:Transforms>
                      <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                      <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                   </ds:Transforms>
                   <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                   <ds:DigestValue>2OfXB/5aD7ajy9AB5o0lMfvcIxOMmrXsdGoAAJeVyLA=</ds:DigestValue>
                </ds:Reference>
             </ds:SignedInfo>
             <ds:SignatureValue>OWp2PGIgzezP+cDKkY2bWOwC7HI5ivs/DlTqdacpwlRcUEWjOUEAFc12rsazjZjR/1VuwE6zoOUK
    fMnYX6zPROemLGMJhET51F1Uf0aRiqrS3dWAU1YlVUrM6ltsWcIgACtnqBdDnqzbRhXTJo7B+zlD
    xFYxItNGVHGVzGK8IvI/dJ+UQ7gcLaOBVfA54ICoJY1qgwKWMzFDg5aYadkm6u/a/fTRvXiZlt3a
    PzR/6/o8I1JgPpvvluJMNAzPR/pvb2tBbY+lufQEUVcsT3p+uq2g/csmfZ02JI/yR2isyrgVOFWA
    Gm+w4cHMhah/MTzsMOTgtMibhPgcsfrl5uzAiA==</ds:SignatureValue>
             <ds:KeyInfo>
                <ds:X509Data>
                   <ds:X509SubjectName>ST=California,C=US,OU=Google For Work,CN=Google,L=Mountain View,O=Google Inc.</ds:X509SubjectName>
                   <ds:X509Certificate>MIIDdDCCAlygAwIBAgIGAVZLKTCAMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMHsxFDASBgNVBAoTC0dvb2dsZSBJ
    bmMuMRYwFAYDVQQHEw1Nb3VudGFpbiBWaWV3MQ8wDQYDVQQDEwZHb29nbGUxGDAWBgNVBAsTD0dv
    b2dsZSBGb3IgV29yazELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAgTCkNhbGlmb3JuaWEwHhcNMTYwODAy
    MTIxMDA1WhcNMjEwODAxMTIxMDA1WjB7MRQwEgYDVQQKEwtHb29nbGUgSW5jLjEWMBQGA1UEBxMN
    TW91bnRhaW4gVmlldzEPMA0GA1UEAxMGR29vZ2xlMRgwFgYDVQQLEw9Hb29nbGUgRm9yIFdvcmsx
    CzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMwEQYDVQQIEwpDYWxpZm9ybmlhMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8A
    MIIBCgKCAQEAkp+4zL/F7fIrGKNIA0wBDKkYT7s0EcV5keuwWoxNA3v7fsAaNelzM+YAVdChKwVZ
    F4wj26iFZvY/Mf48ZHOYVFCvxKAZ8iWniKPhJu07j8y8UjrdMTToGPMRj+P9HDJ+pKglFKmGpuUZ
    Ndhp6jwjTGTPGmSONARUv/hHyH9NTEFtt9E+xsa2X2Gpy0BUgAqG1efd4bQDhwQXD6whrG49VkW6
    7PDh2Lpon+5ssslgnFugLa5jfKc6dO3mGKo9Z+LJBG6yt+ZHjVmwUcIVF2MoENNBR8ZiZlsR9v7a
    53CFWbv/uPvrPr8tGLBw5WZi5EGR8ZqhSzNYqUMRMN7twOQ4PwIDAQABMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUA
    A4IBAQAyFxYhD9I3+/ddBxo9BYGRBzdFe/1EdWZ0S0SC64Zi2Irlj/1qBY2QrQhAxI1z60/J7qyL
    VAMwtw0ZV+vY1UWYPRPum6F5zlMDJbx1xZjxxJCzxpm68aRxWT1vdu0rtaD7H1aKrTWKZZj7rcaK
    mdc5/D3PQfvdgaq0NBFRuYEMZtDXxLXBUvnKx0FoBWpy8NTVRzuHwhmH9wblHg7iVCnkms59cd4A
    Gk/RRh0Ml/U2uJrHeo2fNk2apfsapX6l7PlsRswyDISB+gA7AMGFXQ0ni74QGHY1SqEGDrdnVb3L
    E41EWIiLsm5gDTmVCG1mMfXNucGXoLrJxFOUFawgk5Av</ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
             </ds:KeyInfo>
          </ds:Signature>
          <saml2:Subject>
             <saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">rishi.mi@media.net</saml2:NameID>
             <saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
                <saml2:SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="a40fdeb955aahd123d63ejegi5feh0f" NotOnOrAfter="2016-08-08T12:54:33.806Z" Recipient="https://vogon.srv.media.net:8080/saml2/acs" />
             </saml2:SubjectConfirmation>
          </saml2:Subject>
          <saml2:Conditions NotBefore="2016-08-08T12:44:33.806Z" NotOnOrAfter="2016-08-08T12:54:33.806Z">
             <saml2:AudienceRestriction>
                <saml2:Audience>http://vogon.srv.media.net</saml2:Audience>
             </saml2:AudienceRestriction>
          </saml2:Conditions>
          <saml2:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2016-07-27T11:42:05.000Z" SessionIndex="_09e40853eaac6e2dcceecd6da54fc927">
             <saml2:AuthnContext>
                <saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:unspecified</saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>
             </saml2:AuthnContext>
          </saml2:AuthnStatement>
       </saml2:Assertion>
    </saml2p:Response>
```

This is securityContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- Enable auto-wiring -->
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <!-- Scan for auto-wiring classes in spring saml packages -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.security.saml"/>

    <!-- Unsecured pages -->
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/favicon.ico"/>
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/images/**"/>
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/css/**"/>
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/logout.jsp"/>
    <!--<security:http security="none" pattern="/saml2/acs"/>-->


    <!-- Security for the administration UI -->
    <security:http pattern="/saml/web/**" use-expressions="false">
        <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/saml/web/metadata/login"/>
        <security:form-login login-processing-url="/saml/web/login" login-page="/saml/web/metadata/login" default-target-url="/saml/web/metadata"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/saml/web/metadata/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/saml/web/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        <!--CHANGE-->
        <!--<security:custom-filter before="FIRST" ref="metadataGeneratorFilter"/>-->
    </security:http>

    <!-- Secured pages with SAML as entry point -->
    <security:http entry-point-ref="samlEntryPoint" use-expressions="false">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
        <!--CHANGE-->
        <!--<security:custom-filter before="FIRST" ref="metadataGeneratorFilter"/>-->
        <security:custom-filter after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="samlFilter"/>
    </security:http>

    <!-- Filters for processing of SAML messages -->
    <bean id="samlFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
        <security:filter-chain-map request-matcher="ant">
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/login/**" filters="samlEntryPoint"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/logout/**" filters="samlLogoutFilter"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/metadata/**" filters="metadataDisplayFilter"/>
            <!--<security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SSO/**" filters="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter"/>-->
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml2/acs/**" filters="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SSOHoK/**" filters="samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SingleLogout/**" filters="samlLogoutProcessingFilter"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/discovery/**" filters="samlIDPDiscovery"/>
        </security:filter-chain-map>
    </bean>

    <!-- Handler deciding where to redirect user after successful login -->
    <bean id="successRedirectHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/"/>
    </bean>

    <!--
    Use the following for interpreting RelayState coming from unsolicited response as redirect URL:
       -->
    <!--<bean id="successRedirectHandler" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLRelayStateSuccessHandler">-->
    <!--<property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/" />-->
    <!--</bean>-->


    <!-- Handler deciding where to redirect user after failed login -->
    <bean id="failureRedirectHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
        <property name="useForward" value="true"/>
        <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login.jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Handler for successful logout -->
    <bean id="successLogoutHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler">
        <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/logout.jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <!-- Register authentication manager for SAML provider -->
        <security:authentication-provider ref="samlAuthenticationProvider"/>
        <!-- Register authentication manager for administration UI -->
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service id="adminInterfaceService">
                <security:user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <!-- Logger for SAML messages and events -->
    <bean id="samlLogger" class="org.springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger"/>

    <!-- Central storage of cryptographic keys -->
    <bean id="keyManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager">
        <constructor-arg value="classpath:security/samlKeystore.jks"/>
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="nalle123"/>
        <constructor-arg>
            <map>
                <entry key="apollo" value="nalle123"/>
            </map>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="apollo"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Entry point to initialize authentication, default values taken from properties file -->
    <bean id="samlEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint">
        <property name="defaultProfileOptions">
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileOptions">
                <!--<property name="binding" value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"/>-->
                <property name="includeScoping" value="false"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- IDP Discovery Service -->
    <bean id="samlIDPDiscovery" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLDiscovery">
        <property name="idpSelectionPath" value="/WEB-INF/security/idpSelection.jsp"/>
    </bean>


    <!-- The filter is waiting for connections on URL suffixed with filterSuffix and presents SP metadata there -->
    <bean id="metadataDisplayFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataDisplayFilter"/>

    <!-- Configure HTTP Client to accept certificates from the keystore for HTTPS verification -->
    <!--
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.trust.httpclient.TLSProtocolConfigurer">
        <property name="sslHostnameVerification" value="default"/>
    </bean>
    -->

    <bean id="metadata" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
        <!-- my SP_metadata had this as the entity id -->
        <property name="hostedSPName" value="http://vogon.srv.media.net"/>
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ResourceBackedMetadataProvider">
                            <constructor-arg>
                                <bean class="java.util.Timer"/>
                            </constructor-arg>
                            <constructor-arg>
                                <bean class="org.opensaml.util.resource.ClasspathResource">
                                    <constructor-arg value="/metadata/mnet_sp.xml"/>
                                </bean>
                            </constructor-arg>
                            <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                        </bean>
                    </constructor-arg>
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                            <property name="local" value="true"/>
                            <property name="securityProfile" value="metaiop"/>
                            <property name="sslSecurityProfile" value="pkix"/>
                            <property name="signMetadata" value="true"/>
                            <property name="signingKey" value="apollo"/>
                            <property name="encryptionKey" value="apollo"/>
                            <property name="requireArtifactResolveSigned" value="false"/>
                            <property name="requireLogoutRequestSigned" value="false"/>
                            <property name="requireLogoutResponseSigned" value="false"/>
                            <!--<property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="false"/>-->
                            <!--<property name="idpDiscoveryURL"-->
                            <!--value="https://vogon.reports.mn:8080/context/saml/discovery"/>-->
                            <!--<property name="idpDiscoveryResponseURL"-->
                            <!--value="https://vogon.reports.mn:8080/context/saml/login?disco=true"/>-->
                        </bean>
                    </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
                <!-- Example of classpath metadata with Extended Metadata -->
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ResourceBackedMetadataProvider">
                            <constructor-arg>
                                <bean class="java.util.Timer"/>
                            </constructor-arg>
                            <constructor-arg>
                                <bean class="org.opensaml.util.resource.ClasspathResource">
                                    <constructor-arg value="/metadata/GoogleIDPMetadata-media.net.xml"/>
                                </bean>
                            </constructor-arg>
                            <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                        </bean>
                    </constructor-arg>
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                        </bean>
                    </constructor-arg>
                </bean>

            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
        <!-- OPTIONAL used when one of the metadata files contains information about this service provider -->
        <!-- <property name="hostedSPName" value=""/> -->
        <!-- OPTIONAL property: can tell the system which IDP should be used for authenticating user by default. -->
        <!-- <property name="defaultIDP" value="http://localhost:8080/opensso"/> -->
    </bean>

    <!-- SAML Authentication Provider responsible for validating of received SAML messages -->
    <bean id="samlAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider">
        <!-- OPTIONAL property: can be used to store/load user data after login -->
        <!--
        <property name="userDetails" ref="bean" />
        -->
    </bean>

    <!-- Provider of default SAML Context -->
    <bean id="contextProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderImpl"/>

    <!-- Processing filter for WebSSO profile messages -->
    <bean id="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter">
        <constructor-arg>
            <value type="java.lang.String">/saml2/acs</value>
        </constructor-arg>

        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successRedirectHandler"/>
        <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureRedirectHandler"/>
    </bean>


    <!-- Processing filter for WebSSO Holder-of-Key profile -->
    <bean id="samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successRedirectHandler"/>
        <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureRedirectHandler"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Logout handler terminating local session -->
    <bean id="logoutHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler">
        <property name="invalidateHttpSession" value="false"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Override default logout processing filter with the one processing SAML messages -->
    <bean id="samlLogoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutFilter">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="successLogoutHandler"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="logoutHandler"/>
        <constructor-arg index="2" ref="logoutHandler"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Filter processing incoming logout messages -->
    <!-- First argument determines URL user will be redirected to after successful global logout -->
    <bean id="samlLogoutProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="successLogoutHandler"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="logoutHandler"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Class loading incoming SAML messages from httpRequest stream -->
    <bean id="processor" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <ref bean="redirectBinding"/>
                <ref bean="postBinding"/>
                <ref bean="artifactBinding"/>
                <ref bean="soapBinding"/>
                <ref bean="paosBinding"/>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 WebSSO Assertion Consumer -->
    <bean id="webSSOprofileConsumer" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl"/>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key WebSSO Assertion Consumer -->
    <bean id="hokWebSSOprofileConsumer" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl"/>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 Web SSO profile -->
    <bean id="webSSOprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileImpl"/>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key Web SSO profile -->
    <bean id="hokWebSSOProfile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl"/>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 ECP profile -->
    <bean id="ecpprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileECPImpl"/>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 Logout Profile -->
    <bean id="logoutprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.SingleLogoutProfileImpl"/>

    <!-- Bindings, encoders and decoders used for creating and parsing messages -->
    <bean id="postBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPPostBinding">
        <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="velocityEngine"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="redirectBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding">
        <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="artifactBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPArtifactBinding">
        <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="velocityEngine"/>
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient">
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager"/>
                        </constructor-arg>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="processor">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl">
                        <constructor-arg ref="soapBinding"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="soapBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPSOAP11Binding">
        <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="paosBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPPAOS11Binding">
        <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Initialization of OpenSAML library-->
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLBootstrap"/>

    <!-- Initialization of the velocity engine -->
    <bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.security.saml.util.VelocityFactory" factory-method="getEngine"/>

    <!-- XML parser pool needed for OpenSAML parsing -->
    <bean id="parserPool" class="org.opensaml.xml.parse.StaticBasicParserPool" init-method="initialize">
        <property name="builderFeatures">
            <map>
                <entry key="http://apache.org/xml/features/dom/defer-node-expansion" value="false"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="parserPoolHolder" class="org.springframework.security.saml.parser.ParserPoolHolder"/>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the cause of the problem was that in the class org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl the maxAuthenticationAge value was low and since I had been authenticated a long time ago by the IDP, my authentication was failing. So just increase this variable's value by setting it in the bean.